# Error when jsonEncoding dart object with Firestore Timestamp

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-go-router

I am building an app that reads data from Firestore and converts the docs to custom objects. Some of the custom objects have maps that contain Timestamp datatye. They might look something like this

```
{
  "2023.12.20-qDxAWJHmww": {
    "date": Timestamp,
    "meet": true,
  },
  "2024.2.07-hiuHUYGUbu": {
    "date": Timestamp,
    "meet": false,
  },
  ...
}
```

When I try to pass the object as an extra parameter in `go_router` I get an error:

```
Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Timestamp' has no instance method 'toJson'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Timestamp'
Tried calling: toJson())
```

I am not sure how to handle this, any help would be appreciated

Comment: where does it happen? what's your code?

Comment: In my code it happens on the line when I pass the object: `context.go('/user', extra: userObject);`

Comment: check https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/topics/Navigation-topic.html and find `Using extra` section

Comment: Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

When you pass data using go_router at that time it will encode the data. Timestamp from firestore is not default data type. Instead of timestamp you can pass the milliseconds since epoch at that parameter. later on while using that data you can convert milliseconds to timestamp using their constructor.